# Knockout js can this be easily modelled

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to model this scenario with knockout js?

Say I have 3 fields:

`Current Income`: If I change this value the `Retirement Income` needs to update to `(Current Income * Percentage of Current Income) / 100`

`Retirement Income`: If I change this value the `Percentage of Current Income` needs to update to `(Retirement Income/Current Income) * 100`

`Percentage of Current Income`: If I change this value the `Retirement Income` needs to update to `(Current Income * Percentage Of Current Income) / 100`

Is this some kind of circular dependency? Can it be modelled using knockout js? I'd assume all fields need to be computed...but I'm not sure how to set default values or use computed observables that haven't yet been declared.

jsfiddle starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/4482/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `read/write computed`:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.currentIncome = ko.observable(1000);
    self.currentIncomePercent = ko.observable(5);

    self.retirementIncome = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var result = self.currentIncome() * self.currentIncomePercent() / 100;
            return result.toFixed(2);
        },
        write: function(value) {
            var result = value / self.currentIncome() * 100;
            self.currentIncomePercent(result.toFixed(2));
        }
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/LkqTU/4503/

Comment: Thanks...clever and elegant way to do it.